# Apollo client update after mutation can't map over original result?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

So basically I want to update my UI after a mutation, but this has truly been a pain, been stuck for a few days now.

Some of my components rely on my root query, and map over the results.

Whenever I create a new resource and update my root query, the original results don't get loaded anymore, which causes a `can't read property map of undefined`, because the result isn't there anymore. Adding a check does nothing, it just keeps loading forever.

This is my mutation:

```
export const withCreateLink = graphql(createLink, {
// Mutate normally gets passed as prop to wrapped component
props({ownProps, mutate}) {
    return {
        // But for updating the store we're actually hijacking mutate to a custom function        
        createLink(url, description, group) {
            return mutate({
                variables: {
                    url,
                    description,
                    group
                },
                optimisticResponse: {
                    createLink: {
                        __typename: 'Link',
                        id: -1,
                        url,
                        description,
                        group: {
                            id: group
                        }
                    }
                },
                update: (proxy, mutationResult) => {
                    const query = getAllGroups;
                    const data = proxy.readQuery({query});

                    data.allGroups.forEach((groupData) => {
                        if(groupData.id == group)
                            groupData.links.push(mutationResult.data.createLink);
                    });

                    proxy.writeQuery({
                        query,
                        data
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
});
```

I just want to simply update my UI by only refreshing the group that my resource was added to. Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforming dataIdFromObject to check for typename does the trick:

```
dataIdFromObject: (result) => {
    if (result.id && result.__typename) {
        return result.__typename + ':' + result.id;
    }
    return null;
}
```

I guess I couldn't write to my cache with just using Id. This is apparently a proposal for default.

Comment: This is the default since 1.0, so you should be fine not providing dataIdFromObject.